# issue with rendering output as gif using matplotlib on windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, rendering, holoviews

i want to use render the holoviews output as gif on windows. I am facing this issue as below and now i waited a long time for the output but nothing is showing up :

WARNING:root:Points05279: Setting non-parameter attribute width=500 using a mechanism intended only for parameters
WARNING:root:Points05279: Setting non-parameter attribute height=475 using a mechanism intended only for parameters
WARNING:root:Points05279: Setting non-parameter attribute size=12 using a mechanism intended only for parameters
WARNING:root:Points05279: Setting non-parameter attribute color=black using a mechanism intended only for parameters
INFO:matplotlib.animation:Animation.save using 
​

I have tried github for the solution but noting is coming up. Because the developer of holoviews know this issue with windows.

hv.renderer('matplotlib').save(map,'file_name', fmt='gif')

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The warnings you are getting are for options that don't even exist in the matplotlib backend, but that shouldn't prevent output.

Comment: i have seen this issue in github but the developers are using d3.js which i dont understand, they say that there is a temporary file which keeps on eliminating the output and it happens only on windows.

Comment: import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
import geoviews as gv
import geoviews.tile_sources as gts
from bokeh.models import WMTSTileSource
hv.notebook_extension('matplotlib')
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

Comment: tiles = {'OpenMap': WMTSTileSource(url='http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png')}
d = pd.read_csv("data.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
d.dropna(subset=['latitude','longitude'], inplace=True)    
popu=gv.Dataset(d, kdims=['tweetCreated'])
pop1=(gv.WMTS(tiles['Wikipedia']) *\
popu.to(gv.Points, kdims=['latitude', 'longitude'],
              vdims=['tweetCreated'], color='black' ,crs=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
hv.renderer('matplotlib').save(pop1, 'test2', fmt='gif')

Comment: thats whole code , last second comment contains the librabies and last one contains the whole code